# How do I shut down a Linux server after running for 60 minutes?

Tags: cron, shutdown

I have a server that it is normally switched off for security reasons. When I want to work on it I switch it on, execute my tasks, and shut it down again. My tasks usually take no more than 15 minutes. I would like to implement a mechanism to shut it down automatically after 60 minutes.

I've researched how to do this with cron, but I don't think it's the proper way because cron doesn't take into account when the server was last turned on. I can only set periodic patterns, but they don't take that data into account.

How could I do this implementation?

Comment: Have a look at `at` (one-time execution).

Comment: I haven't done this, but your login script could start a `sudo shutdown -h +60` which would start a countdown counter of 60 mins for the shutdown (-halt) process.  If you wanted to cancel it, you could `sudo shutdown -c`  (this doesn't use cron though)

Comment: I might have a solution that will shut it down as soon as your task is done. May I know how you run these tasks, by a bash script?

Comment: Depending on the nature of your tasks maybe it's worth running them inside a docker container, so you don't need to worry about switching off a server. The container is created, it runs your tasks, and it's destroyed after that.

Comment: Have you looked into uptime?  You could have a periodic cron job that checks uptime and if the value is > 1hr then initiate init 0.  You could also check ps -ef to see if your process is still running.

Comment: Why not shut it down when your tasks are done, rather than after some fixed amount of time?

Comment: Did you actually implement the currently accepted answer or did you just accept the first answer that was posted? It's good form to wait at least 24 hours to give everyone a chance to post, and that will also lead to better answers.

Comment: Don't expect any real security benefit from this. Most vulnerabilities can be exploited in less than a second, so powering down after an hour isn't going to prevent exploitation. And an attacker who found a vulnerability can wait for you to power on the machine in order to perform the attack.

Comment: @kasperd A good point but I feel that you mostly think about targeted attacks. A server that's only turned on one hour every week will be largely invisible to automated "sweeps".

Comment: @pipe I was thinking both targeted and non-targeted attacks. An attack which scans all of the v4 address space can be repeated over and over again. And since attacks performing such attacks tend to use previously compromised machines to find new victims, it is entirely feasible for them to scan for new targets multiple times per day.

Comment: Re: @kasperd 's comment, I'd rephrase it as saying that you need exactly the same amount of security on your server regardless of how much or little it is actually online.  Note, it's a server so it connected to *something* and that means *something* will know when it's turned on - automated sweeps aren't what you worry about, it's connections of any kind and you can't avoid that so max security all the time is the only way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you execute your tasks as the same user every time, you can simply add the shutdown command, optionally with the option -P, to your profile. The number stands for the amount of minutes the shutdown command is delayed.
Make sure your user has the ability to execute the shutdown command via sudo without a password.

```
echo "sudo shutdown -P +60" >> ~/.profile
```

Added:

After reading most of the other answers I love the option to add "@reboot /<path to script/command>" in (root) cron. Answer given by sebasth as his fourth option.  You may either add the shutdown command or write a small script that executes the shutdown and execute that via cron.
WoJ also has a great solution if you use systemd.

Comment: The time is in minutes, not seconds. Try `shutdown -k -P 3600` vs `shutdown -k -P 60` (`-k` prints wall message but doesn't have other effect)

Comment: But try the command one time first, you don't want an instant shutdown to be bound to your profile!

Comment: I imagine every ssh login would cause a new call of shutdown. Would the counter reset then?

Comment: It might also be worthwhile to mention that logins will not be allowed in the last 5 minutes, as mentioned in the shutdown manpage.

Comment: I believe this solution will ask you for root password and start a new instance of `shutdown` every time a new login shell is launched which may or may not be a shortcoming.

Comment: @JoL - Yes. Based on some experimenting with `shutdown` and checking the times in `/run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled`, it appears that the last `shutdown` commands overrides all previous `shutdown`s, regardless of whether the new time is sooner or later than the previous time. So this solution would shut the system down 3600 minutes after the _last_ login, not 3600 minutes after the _first_ login.

Comment: Note that 60 minutes after login is not the same as 60 minutes after boot. What if you boot the machine and then forget to login?

Comment: You can also set the execute bit but not the readable bit on a script that logs in under a special user to run the shutdown command if you don't have sudo without a password.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You can do the same by editing the rc.local script. It will get run a few times but it shouldn't matter in case of the shutdown command. Also, see the answer that didn't get picked but has many more upvotes, that will provide a clear how-to.

Comment: @sebasth The [shutdown manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) says that time can be `now`, an exact time of day (`hh:mm`) or number of minutes from now (`+m`).  It doesn't indicate how raw numbers are interpreted, although some implementations (eg. "upstart") treat it the same without the `+`.

Comment: maybe fire this off from @reboot in crontab.

Answer (score 70):

There are a several options.

- Provide time directly to `shutdown -P`:

  ```
  shutdown -P +60
  ```

  Note that `shutdown` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html) also points out:

  > If the time argument is used, 5 minutes before the system goes down the /run/nologin file is created to ensure that further logins shall not be allowed.
- Use [`at`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/at.1p.html) command.
- Create a [**systemd unit file**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files) or [**init script**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot) which runs `shutdown -P 60` at startup.
- Use cron's [`@reboot`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) to run command after boot.

  Add to (root) crontab:

  ```
  @reboot shutdown -P +60
  ```

For the last two methods, you could also use `sleep 3600 && shutdown -P now` instead of using time argument to `shutdown` to delay the shutdown for 60 minutes. This way logins are possible to the last moment before shutdown is issued.

Comment: I think with the `sleep` command, you still need to specify a time to `shutdown` - we'd want to use `now` for that argument if we've already done the waiting (but note that you won't get very much warning to save your work before it disappears from under you!).

Comment: Although `shutdown -P 60` works it is not the way how the command should be invoked. According to the man page you should use `shutdown -P +60`. --- Also shutdown without a time argument (in the example `sleep 3600 && shutdown -P`) will be delayed by one minute (like `shutdown -P +1`). As Toby Speight wrote you would probably want to use `shutdown -P now`.

Answer (score 33):

This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

> My tasks take usually no more than 15 minutes. I would like to implement a mechanism to shutdown it automatically after 60 minutes.

If you shut down after 60 minutes, you run the risk that you may be running a particularly complicated problem and just need to have more time. Many of the previous solutions would not make it easy to delay the shutdown.

If the task is not an interactive task, but instead are a scripted task that is automatically triggered from another machine, @sdkks gave [a great solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472761/1989) for that; you really should just task the machine to run poweroff as soon as the script and all its tasks finishes.

However, if your task is an interactive task, I'd suggest to do idle detection instead.

If you do your task in a GUI (X11) you can detect the idle GUI sessions using the approach described here: *[Run a command when system is idle and when is active again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120957/run-a-command-when-system-is-idle-and-when-is-active-again)*

If you do the task through a terminal, you can detect logged in users using the `who` command. You can set up a cronjob that shuts the machine down if `who` returns an empty result. Note that this will be quite a conservative approach; it will not shut down the system if you left the console connected, but idle.

If you want to be a bit more aggressive and disconnect idle terminal sessions as well, you can combine the previous approach with [automatically disconnecting idle SSH sessions](https://www.2daygeek.com/automatically-disconnect-inactive-idle-ssh-sessions/) `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax`. Another approach for this if you don't have SSH, but have a local terminal session, is to use the terminal *idle* time as returned by the `w` command.

Comment: This is a very important point. Whatever you implement - it's in your interest to make sure that you can also *cancel* the shut down.

Comment: Something has gone wrong if it is still running at 60m, so maybe just start again. This can very expensive cloud-wise. Not ensuring a shutdown on one occasion set me back over $4,000.

Answer (score 8):

Although previous answers here all satisfy the requirement to perfection, you can also make your machine power off as soon as the tasks are done.

`bash` scripts can be `trap`ped, meaning certain signals can be intercepted and certain tasks can be executed when needed. `EXIT` is one of the signals that can be trapped.

You would be able to:

1. Set a `trap` for `EXIT` of your automated shell scripts, meaning
   termination of your automated tasks
2. Set a `trap` for your `.bashrc` `EXIT`, meaning whenever you log out
   of that machine, power it off.

Option #1 would be the ideal case, provided your tasks don't require adhoc inspection and manual judgement.

Option #2 would cover the cases where you'd forget to exit the terminal without powering off. There is a caveat though; if you have multiple terminals to the same machine open and you exit from one of them, it will still power off the machine all the same. (It can be scripted to avoid that, but I won't complicate the solution.)

```
cleanup(){
    # Do some tasks before terminating
    echo oh la la, cleaning is so nice
    echo "See you later, world"
    sudo poweroff & # finally shutdown
}
trap cleanup EXIT
```

This can be at the end of `.bashrc` for option #2, at somewhere at the top of your script for option #1.

**Why not use `poweroff` at the end of the script?**

I prefer to use `set -eo pipefail` at on the top of my scripts. If any error happens, it won't silently fail; it will stop executing more commands. `trap` of `EXIT` signal should cover the cases where the script terminates prematurely due to errors.

However for your tasks, this might also mean the machine will shut down before they are completed.

I have a simple `bash` template I use for making scripting easier to debug; maybe it might be of some use. Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sdkks/60d9c301295fc23e644f65ce010957e9).

Comment: Agreed, and to be sure maybe a time of day shutdown from cron.  This is a dead man's brake.

Comment: @Abigail for script, it has to be above, for `.bashrc` I’d prefer the bottom in case something else overwrites it. Your concern doesn’t seem clear, can you share an example snippet on repl.it maybe?

Comment: @mckenzm I don’t understand. Can you share sample code or more explanation?

Answer (score 5):

The following runs `command` with parameters, and if it completes successfully it will turn off the box immediately, assuming the user can run `poweroff`. It may need to use `sudo poweroff`.

```
command --parameters && poweroff
```

---

Whereas the following one simply runs `poweroff` immediately when the command terminates:

```
command --parameters ; poweroff
```

---

If you think the command needs rest time after completion, run

```
command --parameters ; sleep 3600 ; poweroff
```

---

If you think the command might run overtime you can constrain it to an hour:

```
timeout 1h command --parameters ; poweroff
```

`timeout` is part of the `coreutils` package so you probably already have it.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on @dirkt comment, you can insert an `at` command on your `.bashrc` or `.profile` or whichever file your shell uses on login to schedule an automatic shutdown 60 minutes after your login.

Something like:

```
at now + 60 minutes -f /sbin/halt
```

Comment: This task is right up `at`’s alley. You can also see `at` tasks in `/var/spool/`

Comment: I would advice against using `at` in this context because it survives reboots. If OP were to log in, manually shutdown and then log in again in the span of an hour, he'd get kicked off before an hour passed after his last login when the first scheduled shutdown proc.

Comment: @Aaron that’s true. Haven’t thought of that. Boot persistence is a caveat for this solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you're really concerned about security, use an mechanical outlet timer on the power source. Just set it to whatever time you want it to shutdown. This way no one can login remotely and disable the shutdown. You would need physical access.

Comment: Filesystem corruption?

Comment: @Xen2050 not a problem on any modern (journaling) filesystem.

Comment: However, a better solution would indeed be to have poweroff system that can send proper SNMP signals for a clean shutdown.

Comment: @Tom Do you have a source for forced umounts will never cause filesystem corruption if there's journaling? Sounds new to me, I'd like to read up on it. At the very least it must mark the filesystem as dirty, forcing a fsck right?

Comment: In most cases, it should just replay the journal and be done with it. A powerdown should not cause filesystem corruption on a journaled filesystem, though there are no guarantees unless you use a filesystem such as ZFS which is specifically designed for this case.

Comment: @Xen2050 - The basic mode of operation for journaling filesystems is that they first write a journal entry saying "I'm going to write this data to block X", then write to block X, then delete the journal entry. If power is lost in step 1, it's a bad journal entry and discarded on restart; the write is lost, but the fs is intact. If it's lost in step 2, the journal entry has enough information to complete the write as if nothing had happened. If lost in step 3, the write is repeated, but it's just re-writing the same data to the same block, so no problems. No fsck is needed in any case.

Comment: Journal replay can fail - I had a very difficult fsck session a couple of weeks ago following a ½-second power cut to a machine with no UPS.  That was using ext4 with a journal; it's not completely invincible!

Comment: on a system where security is paramount, you'll probably using a raid device with a battery backup anyways.

Comment: @gogators Depends on what kind of security you're after. Battery-backed RAID (except RAID 0) can help against some kinds of threats, but be utterly useless or even counterproductive against others. "Security" is too broad a term to be useful in such a context.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the script (`sudo shutdown -P 3600`) in the `/etc/init.d` directory to run it automatically at startup.

Or try using `anacron`, adding the command in the `/etc/anacrontab` file.
I also suggest to use `nohup` in front of the command to be sure that the command is still working after logout.

Comment: Depending on distro, it might not get executed by just being in init.d

Comment: @sdkks, you're right. Anacron can be also considered. putting the script in /etc/anacrontab, also used with 'nohup' in the event of logout.

Comment: @Saveriofr You can [edit] your answer to improve its quality (better than posting additional info as a comment).

Answer (score 1):

**If you are in a `systemd` machine, you can use a [monotonic timer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#Monotonic_timer)**

The timer unit `/etc/systemd/system/shutdown_after_an_hour.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=shutdown after an hour

[Timer]
OnBootSec=1h

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The timer unit `/etc/systemd/system/shutdown_after_an_hour.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=shutdown after an hour

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/poweroff --force --no-wall
Type=oneshot
```

It is enabled via

```
# systemctl enable shutdown_after_an_hour.timer
```

Its status (particularly how much time is left before the shutdown) is available via

```
# systemctl list-timers shutdown_after_an_hour.timer
```

It will work on the next reboot, it is not useful to `systemctl start` it during the session when it is created as it will either not work (because it was not triggered during the reboot) or shut down the machine right away if past one hour. I do not know which one will happen as a matter of fact, I have never tested that specific case.

Answer (score 1):

### Leverage Your Shell's Logout File

If you only need the server for interactive or non-interactive tasks started by your UID, consider putting your shutdown commands into your *~/.bash_logout* file. The [GNU Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) says:

> When an interactive login shell exits, or a non-interactive login shell executes the exit builtin command, Bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

So, adding "sudo poweroff" or similar to your logout file would power off the server **as soon as you log out** of your current session, or when a non-interactive Bash session calls `exit`. You could also choose to use *at* or pass a time-delay to *shutdown* if you would prefer to defer the shutdown.

For a more interactive approach to this, you might put the following Bashisms into your logout file:

```
# Shutdown unless N or n is pressed within 30 seconds.
shopt -s nocasematch
read -t 30 -N 1 -p 'Shutdown now? (Y/n) '
[[ "$REPLY" =~ n ]] || sudo poweroff
```

### Caveats

There are some caveats you should keep in mind about this solution:

- This will probably work even under a terminal started by X Windows, but probably wouldn't work for an X11 session that wasn't launched by `startx` or similar.
- If you have non-interactive scripts that call `exit`, you may experience shutdowns you aren't expecting.
- Your sudoers file may prompt for a password if you haven't specified `NOPASSWD` for the shutdown commands, or if you haven't called `sudo -v` before running your shutdown command.
- There are probably other edge cases I haven't thought of yet.

In short, you might want to consider whether this approach meets your actual need, or whether a completely different approach such as monitoring for an absence of logged-in users or some other alternative is a better bet. Your mileage will definitely vary.